# How to create generic type using template literal as a key

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have a simple form in React. In order to enable user to update data on server I created a function which takes value of the input field and name of the field, creates an object and sends data to server.

```js
function UpdateSettingsForm() {
  const {
    isLoading,
    settings: {
      breakfastPrice,
      maxBookingLength,
      maxGuestsPerBooking,
      minBookingLength,
    } = {},
  } = useSettings();
  const { isUpdating, updateSettings } = useUpdateSettings();

  function handleUpdateSetting(
    e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    updatedField: SettingsFieldsToUpdate
  ) {
    const value = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    if (!value) return;

    const updatedData: UpdateSettingsArgs<**here must be a template literal value of updatedField equals to one of union type **> = {
          [updatedField]: value,
        };

    updateSettings(updatedData);
  }

  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;

  return (
    <Form>
      <FormRow label="Minimum nights/booking">
        <Input
          type="number"
          id="min-nights"
          defaultValue={minBookingLength}
          onBlur={(e) => handleUpdateSetting(e, "minBookingLength")}
          disabled={isUpdating}
        />
      </FormRow>
      <FormRow label="Maximum nights/booking">
        <Input
          type="number"
          id="max-nights"
          defaultValue={maxBookingLength}
          onBlur={(e) => handleUpdateSetting(e, "maxBookingLength")}
          disabled={isUpdating}
        />
      </FormRow>
      <FormRow label="Maximum guests/booking">
        <Input
          type="number"
          id="max-guests"
          defaultValue={maxGuestsPerBooking}
          onBlur={(e) => handleUpdateSetting(e, "maxGuestsPerBooking")}
          disabled={isUpdating}
        />
      </FormRow>
      <FormRow label="Breakfast price">
        <Input
          type="number"
          id="breakfast-price"
          defaultValue={breakfastPrice}
          onBlur={(e) => handleUpdateSetting(e, "breakfastPrice")}
          disabled={isUpdating}
        />
      </FormRow>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

I use React Query to manage remote state.

```js
  export function useUpdateSettings() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const { mutate: updateSettings, isLoading: isUpdating } = useMutation(
    updateSettingsApi,
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        toast.success("Settings successfully edited");
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(["settings"]);
      },
      onError: (error: Error) => toast.error(error.message),
    }
  );

  return { isUpdating, updateSettings };
}

export async function updateSettingApi(newSetting: UpdateSettingsArgs) {
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("settings")
    .update(newSetting)
    .eq("id", 1)
    .single();

  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error("Settings could not be updated");
  }
  return data;
}
```

How should I implement my types correctly in order to limit field names according to created union type SettingsFieldsToUpdate ? The type of variable updatedField must be a template literal.
Currently my types are:

```js
    export type SettingsFieldsToUpdate =
      | "breakfastPrice"
      | "maxBookingLength"
      | "maxGuestsPerBooking"
      | "minBookingLength";

    export type UpdateSettingsArgs<T> = {
      [key: `${ExtractedSettingsFieldToUpdate<T>}`]: string;
    };

    export type ExtractedSettingsFieldToUpdate<T> = Extract<
      SettingsFieldsToUpdate,
      T
    >;
```

As a temporary solution I have this and everything works:

```js
export type SettingsFieldsToUpdate =
  | "breakfastPrice"
  | "maxBookingLength"
  | "maxGuestsPerBooking"
  | "minBookingLength";

export type UpdateSettingsArgs {
  [K in SettingsFieldsToUpdate]?: string;
}

function handleUpdateSetting(
    e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    updatedField: SettingsFieldsToUpdate
  ) {
    const value = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    if (!value) return;

    const updatedData: UpdateSettingsArgs = {
      [updatedField]: value,
    };

    updateSettings(updatedData);
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I have offended you and that I assumed your temporary solution was copied from the nearly identical version from my previous comments. I will delete all my comments here soon so as not to add noise, and you should probably do the same so that it doesn't appear like you're having a one-sided conversation. I do suggest you try to provide a [mre], which should not just be an excerpt of a larger code base but a standalone self-contained example suitable for others to paste as-is into their own IDEs to work on it.  That will give you a better chance of getting a useful answer. Goodbye.